# How to Upgrade Azure Data Explorer Python Plugin Sandbox Anaconda and Python Version?

Tags: azure, anaconda, azure-data-explorer

I'm using the [Python Sandbox in Azure Data Explorer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/azure-data-explorer-support-for-inline-python-is-ga/ba-p/1283836) to do inference on my data tables.
However, in some of my python code I'll need to upgrade the python() sandbox. (e.g., my models are TensorFlow 2 models instead of TF 1 provided by Py 3.6 and Anaconda 5.2 inside the sandbox).

I was looking online but didn't find any good solution on how to upgrade Azure Data Explorer Python Sandbox Anaconda and Python Version

I've tried to follow the documentation on [Azure Data Explorer Python Sandbox Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/sandboxpolicy), but there's no mention on upgrading the Python and Anaconda version

Another information that I've found is the dependencies versions are shown in the [Anaconda page](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/old-pkg-lists/5.2.0/py3.6_win-64/)

If anyone knows of a solution or any information to run this python sandbox upgrade that'd be really great
Or if it's not possible can anyone suggest me what other Azure solution I might use to do inference on my data tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version based on Python 3.10.8 + latest packages. This version is still in preview, in few weeks it would be GA. Currently this upgrade is not yet self service, you should contact ADX support to perform the upgrade.